# How can i use older version of google play services?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm using Google Cloud messaging through google play services. The things is it only works on the devices with last version of play services installed, in remaining devices i need to show a dialog to send user to google play to install new version witch i really don't want to do!

So how can i avoid this?! I'm trying to use an older version of play services (lets say from 2 years ago) to insure majority of my users don't need to update but it seems impossible with grade and android sdk since it already deleted older versions! So what should i do? Is there any way to use older versions?! and if do find a way to use an older version are newer versions compatible with older one?

I don't want to force my users to update because

- GCM it's not essential to my app although i like to have it!
- It's over 30 MB witch is a lot in  third world countries were my users are.
- Google play blocks some of my users from accessing google play due to international lows! and i have to do update manually my self!

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for android studio:

1.Close your project

2.Browse to the folder where your projects has been saved

3.Go to folder 'app' and open the file 'build.gradle'

4. find this line :

   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`

and change the version (here 7.3.0) to an older one (like 6.5.87).
You can find out available versions by looking at sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services

5.open the project again

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Cloud Messaging was only added to the Play Services API in version 7.5, which was released end of May 2015 (see [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-closer-look-at-google-play-services-75.html)).

So, if you manage to find a copy of the v7.5 API (see [my question regarding that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793508/reliable-source-for-older-releases-of-google-play-services-api?noredirect=1#comment55353843_33793508)) or if the suggestion above by @Babak is safe (still investigating that one... and you can only go down to 7.5.0 before you lose GCM support), you might be able to gain a few months, but it will likely not make a huge difference...

Actually, I just noticed that your question was also posted end of May... So you probably won't be able to gain anything. But you may **reduce** support of you move to a new API version later!